# Converting strings from txt to int results in an error

Tags: python

Trying to grab these numbers for example from a text file :

```
00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

Trying to substract the total string that I got from the text file to have a function doing stuff with each row as an integer this way:

```
import linecache

with file('textfiletest.txt', 'r') as original: testfile = str(original.read())
lines = len(testfile.splitlines())
for i in range(lines):
    SID = int(testfile[5*i: -(len(testfile)-5*(i+1))])
    print SID
```

This code results in printing all the lines and getting an error on the last one, saying its not a convertable char.

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Note: every line is 5 characters long.

Comment: Caused by the newline (`\n`) at EOF, maybe? Filter inside the `for i in range(lines): if i != \n: ...`

Comment: Why are you not just looping over the `splitlines()` result *directly*? This looks needlessly complicated. And your slice uses negative indices, so you *probably* end up with empty strings.

Comment: This is really a weird way to get the data.

Comment: The `linecache` module import is entirely redundant here, btw. It doesn't do what you probably think it does, in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line reading in Python is so much simpler than that, you are really overcomplicating things here:

```
with file('textfiletest.txt', 'r') as original:
    for line in original:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        SID = int(line)
        print SID
```

This loops over the lines in the file directly, one by one. `int()` can handle extra whitespace, including the newline character, so all we need to take care of is making sure we skip lines that are empty apart from whitespace.

Your solution doesn't take into account that the newline characters take up space too; lines are 6 characters long *with* the newline. But why make it so hard for yourself when you clearly already found the `str.splitlines()` function; you could just have looped over that:

```
for line in testfile.splitlines():
    # ...
```

would have given you a loop over the lines in the file contents without trailing newlines and certainly no need for complicated slicing computations.